# Flashes not showing in test environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara, integration-testing

I am currently writing integration tests with rspec. The test I have a problem on is fairly symple:

**accounts_controller.rb**

```
def create
  @account = Account.new(account_params)
  authorize @account
if @account.save
  flash[:notice] = 'Your account has been successfully created'
  redirect_to :root
else
  render :new
end
```

**sign_up_spec.rb**

```
require 'rails_helper'

feature 'Accounts' do
  scenario 'creating an account' do
    visit root_path
    click_link 'Get Started'
    fill_in 'Name', with: 'Test'
    click_button 'Create account'
    save_and_open_page
    success_message = 'Your account has been successfully created'
    expect(page).to have_content(success_message)
  end
end
```

The problem is, in development the flash message noticing a successful account creation **does** appear, but when I launch the test suite, i get an error from rspec saying that it didn't found the success message, and indeed after using `save_and_open_page`, nothing appears on screen...

**Test logs**

```
Started POST "/accounts" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-05-04 18:27:20 +0200
Processing by AccountsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "account"=>{"name"=>"Test"}, "commit"=>"Create        account"}
  [1m[36m (0.1ms)[0m  [1mSAVEPOINT active_record_1[0m
  [1m[35mSQL (0.3ms)[0m  INSERT INTO "accounts" ("name",    "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"  [["name",    "Test"], ["created_at", "2017-05-04 16:27:20.224700"], ["updated_at",  "2017-05-04 16:27:20.224700"]]
  [1m[36m (0.1ms)[0m  [1mRELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_1[0m
Redirected to http://localhost/
Completed 302 Found in 6ms (ActiveRecord: 0.7ms)
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-05-04 18:27:20 +0200 
Processing by PagesController#home as HTML
  Rendered pages/home.html.erb within layouts/home (5.0ms)
  Rendered shared/_navbar_home.html.erb (1.1ms)
  Rendered shared/_flashes.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered shared/_footer.html.erb (0.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 10ms (Views: 9.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Comment: Add the test.log output for the failing test to you question.

Comment: I edited my question with the logs

Comment: The log shows that it is redirecting to root so the account creation is probably succeeding, how are you flashes actually displayed (do they require JS to appear on the page)?

Comment: yes this is what I think as well. They do not require any JS, it is plain html that I put after testing if a notice or alert is present. The weird thing is it works perfectly in development..

Comment: The one issue that may be a problem is that it's redirecting to http://localhost, so the session cookie (which contains the flash) may be being set on host 127.0.0.1 (or www.example.com, etc depending on where the original request was made to) and therefore not sent with the redirect.  Any idea what hostname the initial request is using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best guess is that your initial `visit root_path` is using the rack_test driver default_host of 'www.example.com'.  This means the session cookie (which contains the flash) is being set for 'example.com' and therefore not sent along when the app is redirected to `http://localhost` since the domains don't match.  One solution would be to change from `redirect_to :root` (which ends up calling `url_for(:root)` to determine the destination) to `redirect_to root_path` which would just use the current hostname when redirecting.

Comment: that was it! I was indeed looking for the default_host parameter as I was pretty sure the error was coming from there. Works like a charm now, thanks again.